# Unreference shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr

I know 2 ways:

```
// Declared somewhere but not on stack
shared_ptr<X> xptr = make_shared<X>();

xptr = nullptr;  //#1
xptr.reset();  //#2
```

As for me *#1* looks better, but what is better from the point of `C++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is objectively better. In almost every case, the difference is purely aesthetic.

The only exception that I can think of is writing a generic function template that works with both smart, and bare pointers. only `ptr = nullptr` is valid syntax for bare pointers.

The assignment and reset member function differ in behaviour only when the pointer is not null.